# ng-hide animation flicker with interent explorer 11

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, animate.css

I'm trying to use animate.css with ng-hide. All works fine on Firefox and Chrome. But there's a flicker with IE 11. How can I fix that?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="hide" />hide</label> <br />
    {{hide}}<br />
   <div class="fade-in square" ng-hide="hide">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

/* js */

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.anim = 'fade-in';
    $scope.hide = false;
});
```

/* css */

```
    .fade-in.ng-hide-remove { -webkit-animation:fadeIn 1s; animation:fadeIn 1s; }
    .fade-in.ng-hide-add-active { -webkit-animation:fadeOut 1s; animation:fadeOut 1s; display:block!important;}
    .ng-hide {
        display:none!important;
    }

.square {background: darkgreen; height: 200px; width:300px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ashraffayad/7MLLC/

Comment: @AshrafFayad you solved this issue ?